# android search view on grid view with images does not give correct search result.

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a search function for android's grid view. However, every time i search a image , i do not get the correct image with its text. Below is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated :) My filter logic seems to be correct based on the log statements that i printed out. However the image and text is not filtered correctly.

MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String TAG = "MainActivity";

GridView searchGrid;
ImageAdapter adapter;
int[] resourceIds = new int[]{R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2,
        R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5};
String[] names = new String[]{"sample 0", "sample 1", "sample 2", "sample 3", "sample 4",
        "testImage"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    searchGrid = findViewById(R.id.searchGrid);





    adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, this.getModels());

    searchGrid.setAdapter(adapter);

}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_food);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private List<DataModel> getModels() {
    List<DataModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
    DataModel dm;

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        dm = new DataModel(resourceIds[i], names[i]);
        models.add(dm);
    }
    return models;
}

class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<DataModel> dataModels;
    private List<DataModel> filterList = new ArrayList<>();


    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<DataModel> dataModels) {
        mContext = context;
        this.dataModels = dataModels;
        this.filterList.addAll(dataModels);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return dataModels.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return dataModels.indexOf(getItem(i));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ImageView imageView;
        if (view == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imageView.setImageResource(dataModels.get(i).resourceId);
            textView.setText(dataModels.get(i).imageName);
        }
        return view;
    }


    public void filter(CharSequence text) {
        String query = text.toString().toLowerCase();
        //Log.i(TAG,query);
        dataModels.clear();
        if (text.length() == 0 ) {
            dataModels.addAll(filterList);
        } else {
            for (DataModel dm : filterList) {
                if (dm.imageName.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                    Log.i(TAG,dm.imageName + " " + query);
                    dataModels.add(dm);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

MainActivity xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
   android:padding="20dp"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/searchGrid"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:columnWidth="120dp"
   android:gravity="center">

</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

single_item xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    />
```

search_manu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search_food"
    android:title="Search Myfoods"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter code is alright but you are not displaying the items properly. Even when your view is already initialized you need to fill correct data in the views else the view will show previous items data. Modify your code like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    imageView.setImageResource(dataModels.get(i).resourceId);
    textView.setText(dataModels.get(i).imageName);
    return view;
}
```

Also try using holder pattern so that you don't have to find view by its id everytime. It will save some run time on UI thread

Comment: Thanks for your help :) it worked ! could you explain why my precious get view code does not work again ?

Comment: As i explained in the answer, your getView method will be called sometimes with a null view and sometimes with a view that you have used previously. In case your view is null you have to inflate it again and set the new values. While if you get a previous view, you don't have to inflate it again but you have to update the values. In your code you were only settings the new values in case of null view hence the inconsistency.

Comment: Up Vote it if i have helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code like this. Maybe it helps.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ImageView imageView;
        if (view == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
        }
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageView.setImageResource(dataModels.get(i).resourceId);
        textView.setText(dataModels.get(i).imageName);
        return view;
    }
```